# R - get names of vectors in a big data frame and exclude the index column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with many vectors and I need to write a formula of the kind:

y ~ a,b,c,..

where a,b,c.. are the names of all the vectors, except y and the first vector containing the index of the frame. I did something like:

```
    xnam <- paste(colnames(data)[], sep="")
    fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+")))
```

(where I have previously removed the vector y from a copy of the data). The problem is that in this way I also get the index vector. How can I remove it? Any suggestion?

Thanks very much!

Comment: what error do you get? you should add that to question

Comment: Also give some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula interface interprets `.` for to specify all other variables. To remove specific variables, just `subset`:

```
summary(lm(hp~.,data=subset(mtcars,select=-qsec)))

Call:
lm(formula = hp ~ ., data = subset(mtcars, select = -qsec))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-39.100 -15.833   1.593  17.677  33.582 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  47.4615   127.7481   0.372  0.71380   
mpg          -2.1924     1.9776  -1.109  0.27957   
cyl           8.8756     9.4878   0.935  0.35970   
disp          0.4537     0.1335   3.399  0.00258 **
drat         -4.3969    15.7096  -0.280  0.78218   
wt          -30.4149    15.2230  -1.998  0.05823 . 
vs           24.1493    18.2235   1.325  0.19871   
am           11.1254    19.2025   0.579  0.56823   
gear          7.5968    14.2172   0.534  0.59847   
carb         19.2907     6.5193   2.959  0.00725 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 25.41 on 22 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.9025,     Adjusted R-squared: 0.8627 
F-statistic: 22.63 on 9 and 22 DF,  p-value: 3.923e-09
```

If you are working with a function that doesn't interpret ".", then you can modify your function to use `setdiff` to remove unwanted variables:

```
as.formula(paste("hp ~",paste(setdiff(names(mtcars),c("hp","qsec")),collapse="+")))
hp ~ mpg + cyl + disp + drat + wt + vs + am + gear + carb
```

Comment: or `summary(lm(hp~.-qsec,data=mtcars))`

Comment: the problem is that I am using the library neuralnet, and it does not let me use the . operator inside the formula!

Comment: @user2099019 OK, I've added an alternative method.

Comment: @Roland Nice, much simpler!